# В чём разница между a += b и a = a + b

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача показать сходство и разницу между a += b и a = a + b.

Я только учу Python 3, и не знаю ещё даже верхушку айсберга, но всё никогда не замечал каких то отличий.

**Чтобы было нагляднее, вот задача**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: различия как минимум в синтаксисе и быстродействии (на счет второго надо тестить, различия минимальные)
сходства - выполняют одно и то же - сложение а и б и присвоение результата а

Comment: Разный результат - например когда пользовательский класс по-разному реализует методы `__add__` и `__iadd__`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`a + b` вызывает метод `__add__` типа, а `a += b` вызывает метод `__iadd__`. Если метод `__iadd__` реализован, то ожидается, что он изменит текущий объект. Если `__iadd__` не реализован, то используется `__add__`. Это можно найти в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Логично получается, что `__iadd__` имеет смысл для изменяемых типов данных, а для неизменяемых `a += b` всегда будет выполняться как `a = a + b`. Среди стандартных типов данных я нашёл метод `__iadd__` только у типа `list`:

```py
In [38]: int.__iadd__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-5812a817bae3> in <module>
----> 1 int.__iadd__

AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute '__iadd__'

In [39]: str.__iadd__
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-e5b885aa9a63> in <module>
----> 1 str.__iadd__

AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute '__iadd__'

In [40]: list.__iadd__
Out[40]: <slot wrapper '__iadd__' of 'list' objects>
```

Попробуем убедиться, что для списков `a + b` и `a += b` ведут себя по-разному.

**Отличие 1. `__iadd__` изменяет текущий объект, а `__add__` создаёт новый.**

В питоне есть функция `id()`, которая возвращает *идентификатор* объекта. Гарантируется, что идентификатор не будет меняться в течение жизни объекта ([документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)).

Посмотрим идентификаторы списков, которые мы сложим по-разному:

```py
In [43]: l = [1, 2, 3]

In [44]: id(l)
Out[44]: 2209362559304

In [45]: l += [4, 5, 6]

In [46]: id(l)
Out[46]: 2209362559304

In [47]: l = l + [7, 8, 9]

In [48]: id(l)
Out[48]: 2209364596040
```

Видно, что после `l += [4, 5, 6]` объект не изменил свой id (то есть изменился исходный объект), а после `l = l + [7, 8, 9]` имеем новый id, потому что питон создал новый объект.

Такое поведение описано документацией как рекомендуемое, но не гарантированное ([These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__)). Тем не менее стоит ожидать такого поведения при работе с изменяемыми типами данных. При реализации собственных классов тоже нужно учитывать указания документации.

**Отличие 2. Реализация.**

Можно посмотреть, как реализованы для списков методы `add` и `iadd` в [исходном коде](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c). Для `add` вызывается `list_concat`, для `iadd` — `list_inplace_concat`. Оказывается, что `list_inplace_concat` (который вызывается оператором `+=`) является обёрткой для `extend`, который принимает любой итерируемый объект (то есть не только списки, но и кортежи, строки, словари, множества и т. д.). А вот `list_concat` строго требует список. Отсюда понятно, почему такое сработает:

```py
In [49]: l = [1, 2, 3]

In [50]: l += 'abc'

In [51]: l
Out[51]: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

А вот такое выдаст ошибку:

```py
In [52]: l = [1, 2, 3]

In [53]: l = l + 'abc'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-c720fd43b962> in <module>
----> 1 l = l + 'abc'

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Вот вам пример, когда при одинаковых операндах мы получаем разный результат.

Но у каждого типа данных могут быть свои реализации этих методов. Конечно, в каком-то типе они будут реализованы так, что всегда будут приходить к одному результату. Но конкретно у списков эти операторы реализованы по-разному.